# How to express level of difficulty in exercises?

Tags: tikz-pgf, exercises

How would it be possible to have graphic expression of level of difficulty in [exercises package](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercise) like in Stewart's book? Let say, to have those colored rectangles around the exercise number.

[image: page with exercises in Stewart's book]

Comment: Doing it is easy (okay, getting them to line up might be a bit tricky).  Modifying a package to do it is harder.

Comment: It is esasy [change the item number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72814/11604) but rather I will add a score at the end of the question,  [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394504/11604) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301081/11604).

Comment: Thanks for help, it could be useful. However, I was thinking to use basic functionalities of exercises package and to have this graphic expression of difficulty. Particularly, it would be useful to have it for \Question command.

Comment: In addition to the Ti*k*Z-free methods, perhaps consider [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430550/121799) as well. If you post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), I am sure you'll get concrete answers.

Comment: Thank you @marmot. It looks really nice. I would then put exercises as items in the list. The problem I need to resolve is to provide answers at the end of the book on those exercises I choose. At this moment it seems that I have to do it manually.

Comment: As I said, if you cook up a minimal working example without colors, I am sure someone will provide you with a nice answer.

Comment: @ВладимирБожовић You could use my question and the excellent answers.https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337356/create-a-custom-numbered-list-with-little-balls-and-gray-rectangle-also-with-th

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano! I really appreciate it. I will use some of it definitely.

Comment: @marmot I tried to make MWE on this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433919/96275 
This is the closest to what I was trying to achieve.